# Young adult novel with cat-aliens and dog-aliens, turn out to be basis of biblical angels and devils

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272117/novel-about-underground-species-of-humans-and-a-historical-satan) reminded me of a book I read in school in the mid-nineties.  In today’s terms it was a young-adult novel, with an adolescent protagonist (?male), initially in a fairly-realist modern Earth setting, but with aliens quickly appearing in a major way.  The aliens were from two highly advanced species — described as cat-like and dog-like, if I remember right — embroiled in a long-running war with each other. It eventually turns out that a previous  visit from these species became the basis for biblical stories of angels and devils.  I think the major plot arc was the protagonist and his allies preventing Earth/humanity from getting annihilated as collateral damage in the conflict.

I read it in English class in secondary school in the UK — I’d guess around 1996, certainly not later than 1998.  By the style, I’d guess it was written in the 80s or 90s.  I’d remembered the title as *Prove Yourself a Hero*, but that seems to be [an entirely different book](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/4973399), not science fiction at all — possibly the book I’m thinking of is titled something similar, or possibly we just read both around the same time and I’ve confused them in memory.

Comment: But most importantly: which were the angels and which were the devils?

Comment: The cat-like aliens were _obviously_ the devils, @JanusBahsJacquet. Based on the average cat's constant plotting to kill its owner, there's almost no need to ask that question! :)

Comment: @FreeMan … if you’re a dog person, that is. If you’re a cat person, cats are of course the angels, and the evil, drooling dogs that are always chasing the poor kitties are the devils.

Comment: Those people are _plainly_ wrong!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's the same book asked about [here](https://ask.metafilter.com/200252/Trying-to-trace-a-YA-book-involving-dog-aliens-vs-cat-aliens-and-mould-as-a-weapon) then the answer could be [Urn Burial](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2478694), by Robert Westall. From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_Burial_(novel)):

> Urn Burial is a 1987 young adult science fiction novel by Robert Westall. It involves alien races who resemble cats and dogs.

It’s [TVTropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/UrnBurial) (obligatory timesink warning) gives more corroborating details:

> Young Cumbrian shepherd Ralph Edwards is out one rainy afternoon seeing to his flock when he comes across one of the ancient cairns that litter Fiend's Fell […] Ralph finds himself thrown into an ongoing conflict between Prepoc's catlike people, the Fefethil, and the dog-like Wawaka […] searching for hidden weapons from an ancient conflict that saw its final battle played out on a prehistoric Earth.

[One Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3942304076) also notes a “connection to the Book of Revelations and werewolf legends”, fitting the OP’s memory of the aliens giving rise to legends, including biblical stories.

Comment: Thankyou — yes, this is it. From the first discussion you linked I wasn’t quite sure, but searching around further, this is definitely right. If you don’t object, I will edit a few more corroborating quotes into the answer, for the sake of possible future searchers.